# how to add text on top of image in fabric js stack?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have created image layer and text layer using fabric js api. Always text layer is behind the image layer. How to bring the text layer in front?

Answer (score 0):

To bring text layer on top of image layer. Like z- index in css.

You need to set sendtoBack for image. Then text layer will be in front. canvas.sendToBack(img);

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order you are creating the objects. For the text to appear in front of the image, add image object first followed by the text object.